# Android dynamic custom views on a map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm struggling to find a solution to the following problem in Android:
there should be custom views on the map which should animate/expand/etc just like regular views. For instance I need a current user location indicator which "pulsates" on the map, or I need some kind of marker clustering with the following behavior: when I tap on the cluster all the pois from this cluster are animated out evenly spread around the cluster so you can click them individually.

[image]

I've seen solutions involving periodically drawing into bitmap canvas and then updating the marker's bitmap, but it doesn't help when you want to click on the expanded items in the bitmap, also animating a marker with updating it's bitmap would look horrible and clunky.

On iOS for example there is a class `MKAnnotationView` which you can override and draw however you want, why doesn't android have such a simple feature? How can this be achieved in Android? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So you're talking about marker clustering I guess, maybe this link could help you for that:- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering

Comment: Bhavnik, thanks I know about this, but it's irrelevant to my question.